# Should I create separate tables for users and their profiles for a social network database?

Tags: database-design, social-networking

I want to design a database for a social network which will provide profiles for users. Should I use separate tables for users and their profiles or just one table for users and all attributes in it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go big, then do a separate one for the users.

Advantage of users and attributes in same table:

- Simpler SQL query.
- If you assumer that you will always need the attributes, then there's one less join.

Advantage of separate tables:

- In real life, you don't always need the attributes.
- When you need to pair other things with users you don't need all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them separate, Users and Profiles *loosely coupled* would be helpful in the long run.  Profiles can be of communities, groups too not just users, so I suggest keeping them separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a relational database, I would recommend a separate table (normalized, foreign-keys, etc.)

If you are interested in trying one of the document-store databases (e.g., MongoDB, CouchDB, RavenDB), then I would consider first if you normally access attributes when you access a user. If so, then you should place the attributes inside the user as embedded documents.

Good luck!